# Incompleteness of semi recursive languages

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

Let $L=\{\langle M_1 \rangle, \langle M_2 \rangle,...\}$ be a semi recursive language of gödel numbers of turing machines with input alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ which always terminate and decide some language. Show that for every such $L$ there exists a recursive language $D$ (i.e. there is a turing machine that terminates and accepts iff input is in $D$) such that no turing machine $M_i$ with $\langle M_i \rangle$ in $L$ is a turing machine that decides $D$.

As a start I have enumerated the gödel numbers in $L$ and the words in $\Sigma^*$. I want to create an algorithm now which yields a desired language $D$

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hint: are you familiar with diagonalization arguments? What happens when you diagonalize against $L$?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Okay the diagonalization argument ... isn't it that a argument to construct an undecidable language? I.e Suppose we have all list of all turing machines $M_1,M_2,.... $ and list of all words $w_1,w_2,....$ then the language $D=\{w|w=w_i\text{ is not accepted by } M_i\}$  I dont know how we can apply this here. Please respond quick I have to hand in the assignment in 3 hours and wrote something weird which makes use of Zorn's Lemma